# React - Changing a single day forecast to a 5 day forecast

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

Ive recently started to learn React and I've gone ahead and created an app that shows the weather using OpenWeatherAPI. Im only able to display a single day forecast whereas I would like to show a 5 day forecast instead.

As per attached is my code to the app. I have tried to change the Api URL to

`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&cnt={cnt}&appid={apiKey}`

But it doesn't seem to correspond as I get an error message on my console saying that I have invalid API Key which doesn't make sense as I'm able to do it on a single day forecast.

From this App.js what will I need to change to display a 5 day forecast instead of a single day forecast.

[image: My app.js]

Comment: Sounds like you're not calling the API correctly. I'd take a look at [their docs](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5).

Comment: @ChrisB. Hi Chris, I've already tried to apply the api call from the docs you had sent but Im not sure how to implement it or it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

For 5 days data, you should call `${BASE_URL}/forecast` instead of `${BASE_URL}/weather`.

In the text, you typed out `/forecast` but I saw `/weather` in your actual code in the image.

Comment: Hi, would that mean I will need to change all my variables to "forecast" rather than weather, I've checked on their docs but was not able to find anything

Comment: I think you only need to change the URL to `.../forecast` instead of `.../weather` inside the fetch call.